# Why is the number of features in the 1st layer of CNN for MNIST 32?

Tags: conv-neural-network, mnist

Based on the following tutorial:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/v0.6.0/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#deep-mnist-for-experts

Where is the `32` as the number of features in 1st layer of CNN for MNIST coming from?

And where is the `64` as the number of features in 2nd layer coming from?

Answer (score 0):

32 and 64 are the number of filters, they are hyper parameters set by hand just like the numbers of neurons of a full connected DNN network.